# Python flask couldn't get header values in the middleware

Tags: python, flask

I have to planned to use flask framework for my new project. So I have started to study today. I could understand basic routings and middleware. I am trying to read header values in middleware, after that, I need to validate these headers. But I couldn't read the header's middleware. Please see my codings below.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Resource, Api
import middleware

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = middleware.middleware(app.wsgi_app)
api = Api(app)


@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

middleware.py

```
from flask import request


class middleware():
    '''
    Simple WSGI middleware
    '''

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if 'auth-key' in request.headers:
            authKey = request.headers['auth-key']
            print(authKey)
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testuser/Projects/Python/m-registry/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/testuser/Projects/Python/m-registry/middleware.py", line 14, in __call__
    if 'auth-key' in request.headers:
  File "/home/testuser/Projects/Python/m-registry/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/testuser/Projects/Python/m-registry/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/testuser/Projects/Python/m-registry/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Please, anyone, help to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `request` object is created in the Flask app, but you middleware is essentially between WSGI server and this flask app. So you cant access request object in the middleware.

You may try to write your logic as @before_request handler or something like that. For example

```
@app.before_request
     def handle_every_request():
            if 'auth-key' in request.headers:
                authKey = request.headers['auth-key']
                #DO SOEMTHIGN HERE?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flask-http-middleware` for it ([link](https://pypi.org/project/flask-http-middleware/))

You will also have direct access for both `request` and `response`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_http_middleware import MiddlewareManager, BaseHTTPMiddleware

app = Flask(__name__)

class MetricsMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        authkey = request.headers.get("auth-key")
        response = call_next(request)
        return response

app.wsgi_app = MiddlewareManager(app)
app.wsgi_app.add_middleware(MetricsMiddleware)

@app.get("/health")
def health():
    return {"message":"I'm healthy"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```